# PDFTron memory leak zooming

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, memory-leaks, pdftron

I'm working with PDFTron and it works all nice and dandy for doing stuff with PDF's. I made an app with xamarin in which people open up alot of pdf's to sign them. This works fine as well.

The problem starts however when one zooms in and out. Then the memory suddenly starts filling up. After zooming in at a few documents the app crashes..

Anyone an idea what's happening?

This is the activity in which all the magic happens:

### Init PDFViewCtrl

```
    private PDFViewCtrl _mPdfViewCtrl;
    SetupViewer(filePath);
```

### When backbutton is pressed

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        _syncManager = null;
        DisposePdfCtrl();

        Finish();

    }
```

### Saving doc

```
_mPdfViewCtrl.Doc.Save(filePath, 0);
```

### Setup Pdf view

```
private void SetupViewer(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {

        PDFNet.SetDefaultDiskCachingEnabled(true);
        PDFNet.SetViewerCache(100 * 1024 * 1024, false);
        }
        catch (pdftron.Common.PDFNetException ex)
        {
        Logger.log(Title, "Failed to setup viewer");


        }

        try
        {

        Logger.log(Title, $"Setting up pdf viewer");
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PdfView);

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SupportActionBar.Title = "Sign Document";

        Logger.log(Title, $"Toolbar is setup.");
        _mPdfViewCtrl = FindViewById<PDFViewCtrl>(Resource.Id.pdfviewctrl);

        _mPdfViewCtrl.PagePresentationMode = PDFViewCtrl.PagePresentationModes.e_single_page;
        _mPdfViewCtrl.PageViewMode = PDFViewCtrl.PageViewModes.e_fit_page;
        _mPdfViewCtrl.PageRefViewMode = PDFViewCtrl.PageViewModes.e_fit_page;
        _mPdfViewCtrl.SetHighlightFields(true);

        Logger.log(Title, $"Opening file in viewer: {filePath}");

        var docToOpen = new PDFDoc(filePath);
        docToOpen.InitStdSecurityHandler("");

        if (!_allowChange)
        {
            docToOpen.FlattenAnnotations();
        }

        Logger.log(Title, "setting file to pdf viewer");
        _mPdfViewCtrl.Doc = docToOpen;




        var toolManager = new ToolManager(_mPdfViewCtrl);
        Logger.log(Title, "setting file to pdf viewer");
        _mPdfViewCtrl.ToolManager = toolManager;



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Logger.log(Title, $"Error while setting up pdf view: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

### On pause

```
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        DisposePdfCtrl();
    }
```

### On Resume

```
    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        try
        {
        if (!_busy)
        {

            _mPdfViewCtrl?.Resume();
        }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        SetupViewer(filePath);
        }
    }
```

### On Destroy

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    DisposePdfCtrl();

}
```

### Disposing

```
bool disposed = false;
private void DisposePdfCtrl()
{
    if (_disposing)
    return;

    _disposing = true;
    if (disposed) return;
        try
        {
            var oldTool = _mPdfViewCtrl.ToolManager;
            var oldDoc = _mPdfViewCtrl.Doc;

            _mPdfViewCtrl.Doc.Unlock();
            _mPdfViewCtrl?.PurgeMemory();

            _mPdfViewCtrl?.CloseDoc();
            _mPdfViewCtrl?.CloseTool();


            oldDoc?.Dispose();
            oldTool?.Dispose();

            _mPdfViewCtrl?.Dispose();
            _mPdfViewCtrl = null;
            _syncManager = null;
            GC.Collect();
            this.Dispose();

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        disposed = true;
    _disposing = false;
}
```

### On low mem

```
public override void OnLowMemory()
{
    base.OnLowMemory();
    Logger.log(Title, "Low on memory");
    _mPdfViewCtrl?.PurgeMemory();
}
```

Comment: You should try to create a minimal code sample that exbibit the issue

Comment: If only I knew where bad things happen..

Comment: Did  you already debug the code?

Comment: I have forwarded this to Xamarin.Android team here, but in the meantime, what version of PDFNet are you using? You can call PDFNet.getVersion. Also are the leaks on any device you try? Or only certain ones?

Comment: Please contact the support team, create and send us a minimal code sample that allow us to reproduce the issue. Thanks.